# Why isn't my textfield updating?

Tags: swift, textfield

I'm trying to update a textfield in a tableview dynamic cell.

When I first create the cell in

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
```

I can write to it no problem at all it updates how I'd expect. However if I try and write to it later on, it just doesn't update. I have tried putting it in a queue:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    self.textField.text = "test6"
}
```

but still the textfield won't update.

I know the line of code is being called (it hits breakpoints) but I'm stumped as to what could be stopping it.

Comment: If your text field is inside table cell, why not you are creating a custom cell and add a text field inside that cell? This is the standard and best way.

Comment: Can u explain more about if you try to write to it later on it doesn't update? You said it works fine at the beginning. I am confused

Answer (score 0):

All your cell changes should go through tableView(cellForRowAtIndex). If you want to change the text, pass a variable to this function which can be updated elsewhere. Then call tableView.reloadData().